# Data Joining of two Tables MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, union

I have two tables named - 1) `Students` 2) `Classes`. **ClassID** is Primary Key of Classes table and Foreign Key of Students Table.

I want to access one row from the Students table having specfic **RollNo** (This RollNo is given by user input) and all rows from Classes Table.

Students Table is given as:-

```
RollNo   |   SName   |    DOB     |   ClassID   |   Picture
--------------------------------------------------------------
101      | AAAA      | 22/09/2012 | 1           | attachment
102      | BBBB      | 22/09/2010 | 2           | attachment
103      | CCCC      | 22/09/2011 | 1           | attachment
104      | DDDD      | 22/09/2010 | 4           | attachment
```

RollNo is Primary Key. And Last Field of Students is Picture attachment.

Classes Table is given as :-

```
ClassID   |   Class
--------------------
1         | One     
2         | Two      
3         | Three    
4         | Four
```

I want the output like this

### Output

```
RollNo   |   SName   |    DOB     |   Class   |   Picture
--------------------------------------------------------------
         |           |            | One       | 
102      | BBBB      | 22/09/2010 | Two       | attachment
         |           |            | Three     | 
         |           |            | Four      |
```

What is the query to get data like this?

Comment: see My Updated Answer with output see the referance of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left join of Classes to Students:

```
select s.RollNo, s.SName, s.DOB, c.Class, s.Picture
from classes as c left join (select * from students where rollno = 102) as s
on s.classid = c.classid
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives error. `Join expression not supported.`

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan you are right Access does not support such ON clauses. Check my edite answer.

Answer (score 0):

See Here and Try It:

```
select s.RollNo,s.SName,s.DOB,c.Class,s.Picture
from Students s
Left join Classes c on c.ClassID   = s.ClassID
where s.RollNo=101;
```

Here Exactly What You Want:

[image]

Comment: By executing this query only one record is in data set. Also `RollNo` must be given by user input.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan above query exactly what you want with output

Comment: Good effort by you but only one record Row which contains values of `Rollno, SName, DOB, Class, Picture` based on specific `RollNo`. and further Rows with only `Class` column values from table Classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the SQL below is what you are after:

```
SELECT s.RollNo, S.SName, S.DOB, C.Class, S.Picture
FROM Students S, Classes C
WHERE S.RollNo=[Enter roll no];
```

Which gives:

[image]

Regards,

Comment: I appreciate ur answer. But that not what I want. I want one record row from students based on `RollNo` (given by user) and match `ClassId` with this record. And all `Class` records from `Classes` with only this column values.